# restore Mac OS Mountain Lion to factory settings without discs or time machine backups

Tags: macos, backup, startup, restore

I installed XCode 3 on Mac OS Mountain Lion 10.8 and now I am getting the Apple BSODs.

Can I do a system restore without having the discs as I seem to have nothing to use, also I have no Time Machine backups setup.

I cannot get into the machine (as it gets stuck in a infinite boot loop) unless I hold `SHIFT` and go into Safe Mode. `Cmd` + `R` doesn't work, so I can't get into recovery mode.

Thankfully I have little to no data on the disk that I want to keep, so i'd happily return to factory settings - but I don't know how, or even if this is possible.

Here is the screen I am getting on my iMac:
[image]

Comment: So, you don't have a recovery partition? (hold **option** when booting to see if there are other partitions, if it's there it'll show up).

Comment: @sdmeyers There's no `Recovery HD` in the Computer section. I didn't set the machine up unfortunately.

Comment: In this case, unless you have a propper install on an USB drive, I suggest doing an internet recovery, your OS was bought and you can use it from apple's site to re-install it: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718

Comment: You say you can go in to SAFE mode !

Comment: With your Mac running in Safe Mode, you can troubleshoot the issue you were having, such as by deleting an application that's causing problems, removing a startup or login item that's causing issues, or launching Disk First Aid and repairing permissions.

Comment: @Buscar I stand corrected, i _can_ get into the Recovery Mode and it seems there is a `Recovery HD` partition on the disk, although for some reason I cannot see it in Finder. When I hold **Option** I get this screen http://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/. For sure, I have absolutely no Time Bachine backups so I guess that option is out. Can I utilise the second option "Reinstall OS X" _without_ any discs?

Comment: @jackJoe Hey, thanks. I've never had to do any system restores on a Mac before (as you can probably tell). So can I do this over wifi without any discs/software etc through this http://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/ menu? (Option #2)?

Comment: yes Breakfast :), yes you can do option 2, but before you instal new os, try the repair. option 4

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks, that's great. I have a Wifi connection so i'll happily go with that and lose what's on the HDD as there's very little of note. I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 2):

OK,

Reading you question lets clarify few things first.

You say Control-R! but it has to be the Command-R.

Then you say you can get in to the Safe mode!. If so:

With your Mac running in Safe Mode, you can troubleshoot the issue you were having, such as by deleting an application that's causing problems, removing a startup or login item that's causing issues, or launching Disk First Aid and repairing permissions.

If you get in the CMD-R mode use the option 4 first to see if it can be repaired.

[image]

If your Mac problem is a little less common — your hard drive has failed or you’ve installed a hard drive without OS X, for example — Internet Recovery takes over automatically.

[image]